# Adding basic authentication to soap request from spring integration

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-integration

I want to add basic authentication (http authentication) to SOAP web service from spring integration. I am following the approach below to authenticate:

```
<bean id="httpComponentsMessageSender" 
    class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender">
    <property name="credentials">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
            <constructor-arg value="userName" />
            <constructor-arg value="*******" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="uniqueId"
    request-channel="requestServiceChannel" reply-channel="replyChannel"
    uri="end point url" message-sender="httpComponentsMessageSender"
    marshaller="ServiceMarshaller" unmarshaller="ServiceMarshaller">
</int-ws:outbound-gateway>
```

But I am getting this error: `org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Internal Error`

Is there any way to authenticate soap web service by adding basic authentication to it?

Comment: And why would that be related to your basic authentication? Post the full stack trace instead of a snippet.

Comment: Well, Unfortunately I know only the same `CommonsHttpMessageSender` hook to provide Basic Authentication. Since you have it already, the problem is somewhere else. E.g. `Internal Error` may mean that something wrong on the server. You really should consult with the server to figure out what's going on. We don't see the credential issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution finally, here is the solution

```
<bean id="apacheHttpClientParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams">
        <property name="authenticationPreemptive" value="true" />
        <property name="connectionManagerClass"
            value="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="apacheHttpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
        <constructor-arg ref="apacheHttpClientParams" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="credentials"
        class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
        <constructor-arg value="userName" />
        <constructor-arg value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authentication"
        class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender">
        <constructor-arg ref="apacheHttpClient"></constructor-arg>
        <property name="credentials" ref="credentials" />
    </bean>
```